How to correctly update `frame` in relation to `updateUIViewController`
I'm using this camera library in which the author wraps a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer inside a UIViewControllerRepresentable (link) to use it as a camera preview. Inside updateUIViewController, the author queues the frame update with DispatchQueue.main.async:
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        previewLayer.videoGravity = gravity
        if previewLayer.superlayer == nil {
            uiViewController.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        }
        // print(uiViewController.view.bounds) -- point A
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // print(uiViewController.view.bounds) -- point B
            self.previewLayer.frame = uiViewController.view.bounds
        }
    }

There can be discrepancies between point A and point B, which makes sense since using DispatchQueue.main.async won't guarantee ordering, but I'm not entirely convinced this approach is correct. I want to be able to set the frame of this view using something like Preview().frame(width: 350, height: 500). However, the lack of ordering here means that depending on other parts of the app/views, the view.frame update happens at an unknown schedule. For example, the following:
import SwiftUI
import Aespa

@Observable
class ViewModel {
    @ObservationIgnored var aespaSession = Aespa.session(with: AespaOption(albumName: nil))
    @ObservationIgnored var preview: InteractivePreview {
        aespaSession.interactivePreview(
            gravity: .resizeAspectFill,
            option: InteractivePreviewOption()
        )
    }
    var show = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Show Camera Preview") {
                    viewModel.show.toggle()
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .zIndex(0)

            if viewModel.show {
                VStack {
                    viewModel.preview
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 500)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .zIndex(1)
            }
        }
    }
}

Prints:
Point A: (0.0, 0.0, 393.0, 852.0)
Point B: (0.0, 0.0, 350.0, 500.0)

But if you change the code to something else, perhaps a different background at .zIndex(0) (I won't show the exact code here since my app is non-trivial), it might print:
Point A: (0.0, 0.0, 393.0, 852.0)
Point B: (0.0, 0.0, 393.0, 852.0)

So my question is. What is the correct way to set view.frame? updateUIViewController is obviously being called in some deterministic order but not before the bound have "settled". I don't see a magical "updateViewOneLastTime" method?

You'll have better luck with SwiftUI if you remove the class ViewModel and use @State with simple values and pass down with let for readonly or @Binding var for read write. The first problem is @State with an object is a memory leak but there are many more issues. Usually a Coordinator object would hold the camera session within the Representable.

@malhal "@State with an object is a memory leak" -- my understanding is that this is exactly what Apple wants us to do now? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

It's ok in App because that is only init once, but View can be init many times so not ok there. Every time the View is re-init a new object will be init and lost, the States initial value. This is ok for value types.

Not 100% certain if I understood. You are talking about var preview: InteractivePreview getting re-initiated, is that right? Does this change anything? -- i.e. viewMode.preview is re-initialized via UIViewControllerRepresentable using pointers to the camera session, so the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer isn't recreated but reused?

It sounds like you are looking for viewDidLayoutSubviews, which is called whenever the view controller's view.bounds changes. Create a UIViewController subclass and override it.
class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        previewLayer?.frame = view.frame
    }
}

Then change the methods in the UIViewControllerRepresentable implementation to use this subclass. Pass the preview layer to the view controller subclass where appropriate.
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PreviewViewController {
    let viewController = PreviewViewController()
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    uiViewController.previewLayer = previewLayer
    
    return viewController
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PreviewViewController, context: Context) {
    previewLayer.videoGravity = gravity
    if previewLayer.superlayer == nil {
        uiViewController.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    }
    uiViewController.previewLayer = previewLayer
}

func dismantleUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PreviewViewController, coordinator: ()) {
    previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
}


Thank you. This is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not familiar with UIKit... the documentation of updateUIViewController says "SwiftUI calls this method for any changes affecting the corresponding UIKit view controller". So I why isn't this called after the layer's bound changed?

@bli00 updateUIViewController is called when any of the properties in Preview is changed, e.g. previewLayer. These are the properties that potentially “affects the corresponding UIKit view controller”. SwiftUI doesn’t know anything about your UIViewController. The purpose of this method is for you to “synchronise” whatever changed on the SwiftUI side with the UIKit stuff.

Ah ok, so it's like the manual-equivalent of @State change?

@bli00 yeah. updateUIViewController is kind of like the body of a UIViewControllerRepresentable.
